# How do you attach asset tags to camera equipment?

Tags: equipment-protection, business, file-management

For all you pros out there, how do you handle asset tags on your equipment?  It seems easy to apply them to computers, notebooks, external hardrives, and even camera bodies, but how do you handle asset tagging lens, memory cards and other fixed assets?

Answer (score 5):

I don't tend to asset tag any of my camera equipment as it does not lend itself to tagging. I simply enter the serial numbers of the asset into my asset register instead. This is sufficient as the asset register is just a means of tracking fixed assets owned by your company and serial numbers are a valid way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're handling many items, the serial number, while important to record for warranty and repair purposes, isn't sufficient because you need a fast method of counting/auditing the inventory or booking equipment in and out. That means barcode scanning for speed and accuracy, and a barcode label. Due to limited size of flat surfaces, they can be successfully scanned down to a label of 5mm x 20mm. If the item is too small or complex, such as a lens, then tag the box. After that your're ready to work with asset tracking software but that's a much bigger subject which I'm happy to discuss separately.

Regards, Stephen Laing, ASSETtrac Ltd

Answer (score 0):

working in IT, we deal with small stuff like SD cards as well. Those aren't tagged, it's just noted how many of which brand and model are released to whom, and when items need to be returned it's expected that same number be returned.